# Definition of integral of vector field along a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth unit-speed curve $[0,L] \to\mathbb{R}^{3}$, and let $X \colon [0, L] \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a normal vector field along $\gamma$, i.e., a vector field along $\gamma$ such that $\langle X, \gamma' \rangle =0$.

Given a positively oriented orthonormal frame $(\gamma', V, W)$ along $\gamma$, one can write
$$
X = X^{1}V + X^{2}W
$$
for some functions $X^{1}$ and $X^{2}$.

I wonder if the integral

$$
\int_{\gamma}X = \int_{0}^{L} X^{1} \, dt + \int_{0}^{L} X^{2} \, dt
$$
is well-defined, meaning that its value does not depend on the choice of vector fields $V, W$ composing the frame $(\gamma', V, W)$.

I suspect that the answer is *no*. But can one say anything interesting if, for instance, one finds that the integral computed with respect to a particular frame vanishes?

EDIT. As pointed out by lisyarus in the comments, the answer to both question in negative. Would anything change if we assumed the vector fields $V,W$ be closed, i.e., $V(0) = V(L)$ and $W(0) = W(L)$?

Comment: At least you can always change $V$ to $-V$ and $W$ to $-W$ to produce a different orthonormal frame with the same orientation, which changes the signs of $X^1$ and $X^2$ thus changing the sign of the total value of the integral.

Comment: The frames $(\gamma', V, W)$ and $(\gamma', -V, -W)$ have the same orientation: one is a $180^\circ$ rotation of the other.

Comment: The answer to your second question is also negative: consider the case of $X = V - W$, producing the value of zero for the integral. Then, a $45^\circ$ rotation of $(V, W)$ will produce a new basis $(V',W')$ with $X = \sqrt 2 V'$, giving a nonzero value.

Comment: N.B. Both my examples work for cases like $\gamma(t) = (t, 0, 0)$, $V = (0, 1, 0)$ and $W = (0, 0, 1)$, i.e. for the case of constant $V$ and $W$.

Comment: Just write down a general rotation of the frame by angle $\theta(t)$ and compute.